# How do I join an array of strings together in yq?

Tags: jq, yq, data-transform

### My issue

I try to transform a `.yml` file to `.csv` and I cannot managed to perform the following operation on this file.

I want to extract all the properties `name` of each element, in a **single column**, separated by a character (not comma **,**).

```json
[
    {
        "id": "6426edc70426309fa3bb0ccd",
        "labels": [
            {
                "id": "6425a8e74720c87ca4219d8f",
                "idBoard": "xxx",
                "name": "label-red-label",
                "color": "red"
            },
            {
                "id": "642aa09cd201f3dd2e12b6f6",
                "idBoard": "xxx",
                "name": "label-green-label",
                "color": "green"
            }
        ],
        "idLabels": [
            "6425a8e74720c87ca4219d8f",
            "642aa09cd201f3dd2e12b6f6"
        ],
        "name": "titre de la carte 1",
        "url": "https://trello.com/c/url-carte-1"
    },
        {
        "id": "6426edc70426309fa3bb0eef",
        "labels": [
            {
                "id": "6425a8e74720c87ca4219d8f",
                "idBoard": "xxx",
                "name": "label-red-label",
                "color": "red"
            }
        ],
        "idLabels": [
            "6425a8e74720c87ca4219d8f"
        ],
        "name": "titre de la carte 2",
        "url": "https://trello.com/c/url-carte-2"
    },
        {
        "id": "6426edc70426309fa3bb0dde",
        "labels": [
            {
                "id": "642aa09cd201f3dd2e12b6f6",
                "idBoard": "xxx",
                "name": "label-green-label",
                "color": "green"
            }
        ],
        "idLabels": [
            "642aa09cd201f3dd2e12b6f6"
        ],
        "name": "titre de la carte 3",
        "url": "https://trello.com/c/url-carte-3"
    }
   

]
```

> *sample.json*

### What I expect

This is the result I wish to get (with a command I couldn't find yet):

```
id_card,name,labels
6426edc70426309fa3bb0ccd,titre de la carte 1,"label-red-label;label-green-label"
6426edc70426309fa3bb0eef,titre de la carte 2,"label-red-label"
6426edc70426309fa3bb0dde,titre de la carte 3,"label-green-label"
```

I didn't manage to use the `| join(";")` properly, but it might be a solution

### What I've tried

With the following command:

```bash
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}":/workdir mikefarah/yq -o=csv '[[ "id_card", "name", "labels"]] +  [.[] | [ .id, .name, .labels.[].name  ]]' sample.json
```

I get the following result:

```
id_card,name,labels
6426edc70426309fa3bb0ccd,titre de la carte 1,label-red-label,label-green-label
6426edc70426309fa3bb0eef,titre de la carte 2,label-red-label
6426edc70426309fa3bb0dde,titre de la carte 3,label-green-label
```

This is almost correct *but* the names of the labels are splitted by a comma **,** so my CSV file is not valid anymore.

Do you have any idea how I could fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using `[.labels.[].name] | join(";")`  works to put a `;` between each element.

The full command:

```
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}":/workdir mikefarah/yq -o=csv  '[[ "id_card", "name", "labels"]] +  [.[] | [ .id, .name, [.labels.[].name] | join(";") ]]' sample.json
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works exactctly as expected !

Comment: By the way, do you have an idea on how I could rename the issue to be clearer ?

Comment: @codug Sorry, renaming this question, or renaming something else?

Comment: Yes, renaming the subject of the question